# No se puede resolver el símbolo "webview_relative"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

No entiendo por qué me salta este error. Tengo dos proyectos de app diferentes que usan la misma estructura y en el otro no me aparece dicho error.

Estas son dos capturas; una del error (en Main_Activity.java) y la otra del Activity_Main.XML :

[image: Error]

[image: Activity_Main.xml]

No entiendo el porqué del error. Ya que el Activity_Main.xml tiene un RelativeLayout.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se trata de un error tipográfico

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error mío; Estaba mal apuntado. El id de mi webview era diferente webview_relative.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/10953)

Comment: Si proporciona una respuesta. Respondí aclarando cuál fue el error y luego de unas horas voy a poder marcar la pregunta como respondida. Esto es obviamente para que nadie más que entre a esta pregunta pierda su tiempo respondiendo a algo que ya está aclarado con anterioridad. Pd: si aún te quedan dudas sobre la definición de "respuesta", consultá un diccionario.

Comment: Si la pregunta era un simple error tipográfico en lugar de crear una respuesta puedes también eliminar la pregunta. Stack Overflow es moderado por nosotros mismos y este tipo de respuestas siempre serán marcadas como de baja calidad y eliminadas por el sistema. Por favor lee http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers. Las respuestas de Stack Overflow requieren ciertas condiciones que se recogen [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)